# how to upgrade apache on bitnami wordpress ubuntu instance

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, bitnami

I have apache version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
Server built:   Oct 26 2014 13:31:18
```

I want to update apache version for http2 support. But simply adding http2 module in httpd.conf give error saying that module not found and `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade apache` also doesn't work. Didn't find any solution on internet. How can I upgrade apache?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Bitnami WordPress Stack, you have to understand that the Apache installed on the Stack is not installed by `apt-get install XXX` actions. Therefore, you can't upgrade it that way.

My recommendation install the new WordPress Stack available at https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress (this way you're installing the latest version of Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc.) and then migrate your WP from the old stack to the new one as explained in the guide below:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/migrate-wordpress/

After that, you can remove the old Stack.

Comment: This way I need to migrate all my data and custom files to the new instance. This is really not a good way to upgrade a single component.